# What is minimal absolutely required permission to post to user's (or her friend's) wall via any API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I wrote the app that posts to user's wall and the wall of her friend, and to accomplish this, asks for **publish_stream** permission, but now I got the opinion from another guy that this is too much and that there is a simpler way (less scary permissions dialog). However I can't reach him at the moment to ask what he has meant exactly. What is the truth here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any permissions at all with the javascript SDK to call [fb.UI with a 'method' of 'feed'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) because the user will see a dialog box to confirm and enter a message of what they are sharing.  To publish from server-side code like PHP SDK, you will need publish_stream.

Comment: That's the one, it is a few more clicks for the user, but at least the scary permissions dialog really isnt there.

Comment: Is it possible to style the sharing dialog maybe?

Comment: Interestingly enough that resource while it says that the same thing is possible with GraphAPI, doesn't mention any required permission, which is at least confusing for newcomer... :|